# When asked to reference external dll files, do i manually copy them to bin and then reference them from my bin?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, reference, telerik

The telerik instructions say to add references to the assembly from Telerik's installation folder. https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/spreadsheet/getting-started

What i did initially was, i copied that dll from Telerik's installation folder into my project's **bin** folder and then add a reference to that dll in the project (**Add reference**).

I've noticed that when i do not copy the telerik's dll to my bin folder but reference it from its installation folder, when i build it it will copy it to my projects' **bin**.

One difference that i've seen between referencing the telerik's dll from the installation folder vs referencing the dll that i copied to the project's bin folder is that the csproj file will have a "hint" entry with the path from where i referenced it.

1. My question has to do with what is the recommended way to do it?
2. Moreover, when i will deploy it to the dev and staging servers, will these dll's be deployed as well? if yes, then what's the purpose for pointing where the original reference comes from?
3. There was a 3rd question that i had but can't remember so I'll leave this for suggestions for best practices when working with external references/assemblies/dll(s).

Thanks!

---

**PS:** My project is a `asp.net` web forms project and the other one is going to be a asp.net web app (old style)

Comment: _"into my project's bin folder"_ - do you mean you have created the equivalent of a **Lib** folder that you add to source control OR do you mean you copied them into **bin\debug**?  If the latter you shouldn't do that.  Generally devs and CI just have the tools installed in the same path (whether that is **..\Program Files\** or a copy in SCM).  Ideally, the assembly reference is something to that in the GAC then it doesn't matter where the file is, but not all 3rd parties install to the GAC

Comment: I would recommend you ,copy telerik;s dlls in sub folder of your project(create new folder in your solution) and add references to your project from this newly created folder. after that  for each dll you refer, click on properties->select "copy always" option .And build yuur solution.AS result Bin folder will get this dlls.

Comment: 1) It would be ideal to use GAC when installation required on both the dev and deployment server. This way even though all team members can run the solution without any issue. 2) When DLL alone can work then it would be ideal to create an external references folder in the solution and reference those instead of copying into bin folder.

Comment: @MickyD, i actually copied them in bin.... at this moment there is no bin/debug... as for having telerik installed on each server, I'm pretty sure they don't have it. Moreover, i know for sure, based on telerik's documentation, that Telerik.Web.Design.dll is not in GAC (https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/general-information/troubleshooting/design-time-troubleshooting)... so basically, what you're saying is to create a lib folder and copy there all the dlls that i want to add references to?

Comment: @VishalPawar, i am working on an old ASP.NET Web Pages... I see there is an Assemblies folder but i don't know if it's a folder that was created to drop dlls into that we later reference or if it's part of the Web Pages structure. Either way, it seems like what you're saying is to create a lib folder, drop all the external telerik dlls and then reference them from there with the "copy always" option checked.

Comment: @BhasyakaruluKottakota, thanks...